# Are relativistic spacecraft slowed down by oncoming gamma ray photons?

Tags: special-relativity, gamma-rays

I recently read that a proton having an energy of ten billion GeV can travel across our galaxy in about 5 minutes from the frame of the proton. From the Earths frame we would see it take roughly 100,000 years. During this time light from the galaxy would be incident upon the proton and presumably it would be blue shifted to the point of gamma ray frequencies. Would the high energy proton be slowed down as it moves through the galaxy? Would any relativistic spacecraft also have to deal with this problem?

Comment: This is basically asking for the cross section of a PeV/EeV proton + (effectively stationary) photon.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberration_of_light

Comment: The scattering of charged high energy cosmic radiation on the microwave background sets a high energy cut-off for cosmic radiation from remote sources: [GZK limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greisen%E2%80%93Zatsepin%E2%80%93Kuzmin_limit).

Comment: As for ultra-relativistic space craft – that is one of their (lesser) problems, they would probably be fried by high-energy radation.